# spectral radius formula - why does $\sum \xi^n \zeta^{-n}$ converge for $|\zeta| > r(\xi)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, banach-algebras, spectral-radius

Every proof of the spectral radius formula $r(\xi) = \limsup \|\xi^n\|^{1/n}$ for Banach algebras (that I have seen) uses the fact, that if $\zeta \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|\zeta| \geq s > r(\xi)$ (for $s>0$), then the series $$\sum \xi^n\zeta^{-n}$$ converges uniformly and absolutely on $\{\zeta \colon |\zeta| \geq s\}$. But isn't this already using the fact, that $r(\xi) \geq \limsup \|\xi^n\|^{1/n}$, which we essentially wanted to prove in the first place?

> I guess the question basically boils down to why holomorphicity of the function $\zeta \mapsto (\zeta-\xi)^{-1}$ on the resolvent $\rho(\xi)$ of $\xi$ implies, that $(\zeta-\xi)^{-1} = \sum \xi^n\zeta^{-n-1}$ for all $|\zeta| > r(\xi)$.

Comment: $A=-aI$ shows that $I-a^{-1}A$ can be invertible.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Do you understand the explanation given here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2651815/485385 ?

Comment: @Cameron Williams I have seen that one, my comment above yours lists exactly the same link. Yet I fail to understand the explanation given there.

Comment: Oh blerp haha I went on a deep dive here on MSE and forgot you linked something by the time I got back. I think this approach is pretty clean: https://chiasme.wordpress.com/2013/05/17/gelfands-spectral-radius-formula/ .

Comment: Yes I have seen that one too haha. Yet I think this also uses the statement I couldn't figure out how to deduce, since in Claim 3 the author tells us, that $f(\lambda) = \frac{-1}{\lambda} \sum \varphi(A^n)$ for every $|\lambda| > s_A$. Why does this follow from the uniqueness of power series expansion if we do not even know if the said series converges for $|\lambda| > s_A$? I mean by holomorphicity we know that there is a series expansion yes, but how can we be sure it is that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use the symbol $a$ for a nonzero element in a Banach algebra and $\lambda$ for a complex number.

Suppose $|\lambda|\gt \|a\|\gt0$. Then $\frac{\|a\|}{|\lambda|}\lt 1$ and hence $(1-\lambda^{-1}a)^{-1}$ exists.  Also, $$(1-\lambda^{-1}a)^{-1}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\lambda^{-n}a^n.$$ Now, $(1-\lambda^{-1}a)^{-1}=\lambda(\lambda-a)^{-1}$. Thus, $$(\lambda-a)^{-1}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\lambda^{-n-1}a^n\tag1\label1.$$

In other words, if $\lambda^{-1}\in B(0,1/{\|a\|})\setminus\{0\}$(the deleted open ball of radius $\frac1{\|a\|}$ centred at $0$), then $(\lambda-a)^{-1}$ exists and the holomorphic function $\lambda^{-1}\mapsto (\lambda-a)^{-1}$ has a power series representation given as in $\eqref1.$

Notice that $r(a)\leq \|a\|$, so $B(0,1/{\|a\|})\subseteq B(0,1/{r(a)}).$ Now, if $0\lt|\lambda^{-1}| \lt \frac1{r(a)}$(i.e. $|\lambda|\gt r(a)\gt0$), then $(\lambda-a)^{-1}$ exists and the holomorphic function $\lambda^{-1}\mapsto (\lambda-a)^{-1}$ has a power series expansion on $B(0,1/{r(a)})\setminus\{0\}.$
Since we already have a power series on a smaller neighbourhood, the uniqueness implies that the same should hold on $B(0,1/{r(a)})\setminus\{0\}$ as well.

Comment: That's very well written! I guess the uniqueness part is due to the identity theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) and the proof is analogous for Banach algebra-valued analytic functions right?

Comment: @h3fr43nd Thanks for the bounty. I wrote this answer based on the proof of the spectral radius formula given in [this](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387953007) text. Their proof is slightly different than the one given above. You might want to have a look at it.

Comment: I will do that! The proof I had in mind was the proof given in the functional analysis book of Lax. He uses the fact that $$\xi^n = \oint_C \frac{\zeta^n}{\zeta-\xi} d\zeta$$ if C is a circle with radius greater than $r(\xi)$. He didn't explain however why we could argue this identity would hold (since we need uniform convergence, which he only showed for radii greater than $\|\xi\|$), since I guess he assumed this to be a trivial fact. If you are curious for the proof, it is on page 196 and the book is freely available online.